# Beginner issue about make file syntax understanding

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am trying to understand and modify a `makefile` which contains the following code

```
SOURCES= cvode.cpp RcppExports.cpp
OBJECTS= $(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
```

I understand the first line, i.e., assigning to a variable. I am assuming that second line is same as

```
OBJECTS = cvode.o RcppExports.o
```

i.e., same file names as in `$(SOURCES)` but with a `.o` extension. Is that correct?

I read the `GNU make` documentation online but was not able to find the help for this sort of code formulation. Is this a macro?

The reason I am asking is that I need to compile a `C` library on a `Solaris` machine where `GNU make` might not be available. I am trying to make the code more portable by as I got the following error:

```
mksh: Fatal error in reader: = missing from replacement macro reference
```

which might be `GNU make` specific. So my approach is to replace all the code written in the form of second line above (in the first code fragment) with more explicit inputs (as in second code fragment).

Any guidance here would be very helpful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what your question is, but if you're looking for documentation on that it's called a [substitution reference](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Substitution-Refs.html).

Your makefile has a few problems:

First, the `info` function on the first line is only available in GNU make.  You should remove that.  I'm quite confident that this line is what's causing your problem; since the Solaris version of make doesn't recognize the `info` function it assumes this is a variable reference.  Then it sees the `:` in the content (`...to be created is:...`) and believes this to be a substitution reference.  Since there's no `=` after it, you get this error.

Second, the syntax `($SHLIB)` is wrong; I assume you really mean `$(SHLIB)` in both the lines:

```
all: ($SHLIB)
($SHLIB): $(OBJECTS) ../inst/libsundials_all.a
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. The reference you pointed to helps me understand the code better. The documentation mentions - "A substitution reference is actually an abbreviation for use of the `patsubst` expansion function"..do you think this could be making the code non-portable (as this could be `gnu make` specific).

Comment: The docs just mean, here, that the code that implements substitution references is a special case of `patsubst`, to explain it to the reader.  It's perfectly possible for a different version of make to implement substitution references in its own way without supporting `patsubst`.  However it's possible some versions of make don't implement this support.  On the other hand, this syntax _IS_ part of the POSIX standard for the `make` program so I'd expect any POSIX system's implementation of `make` to support it.

Comment: Maybe on Solaris the default `make` is not POSIX?  Is there a `/usr/xpg4/bin/make` on your system?  It's been a long time since I used Solaris but I recall that POSIX-standard utilities were often placed in `/usr/xpg4/bin`.

Comment: Thanks, again. I don't have access to a Solaris system also, the application I am building needs to compile on Solaris also for it to be accepted. Perhaps, you can take a look - the `makefile` can be found at - https://github.com/sn248/sundialr/blob/master/src/Makevars and the error I am getting from the system can be found at - https://www.r-project.org/nosvn/R.check/r-patched-solaris-x86/sundialr-00install.html, The application builds fine on a variety of linux systems - https://cran.r-project.org/web/checks/check_results_sundialr.html, using the same 'makevars' file. Could you please help?

Comment: Wow..just amazing. You have probably solved my problem (which I thought would be impossible to solve) with one look at it. Amazing! And Thank you so much!!!